# WP_ENQUEUE not working with Foundation 5

Tags: jquery, scripts

I've recently started integrating Foundation 5.2.3 into Wordpress 3.9, and I am having issues with getting jquery to initialize via wp_enqueue. The styles load just fine, though.

A working example of what I am trying to achieve can be found [here](http://www.elevancement.com/novus-theme/) (styles & scripts in header.php and footer.php)

functions.php

```
// Enqueue scripts
require_once('library/enqueue-scripts.php');
```

Now in my enqueue-scripts.php

```
<?php

// wp_enqueue foundation_styles
function foundation_styles() {

  // wp_enqueue style, as you do not need to register style links. 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'reset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'foundation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/foundation.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/font-files/font-icons/foundation-icons.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'nprogress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/nprogress/nprogress.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'override', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/project.override.css' );

}

// wp_enqueue foundation_scripts
function foundation_scripts() {

  // wp_enqueue jqeury 
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

  // wp_enqueue scripts 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr-2.5.3.js',null,null, false );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollreveal', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation/foundation.scrollReveal.js',null,null, false );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery110', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/jquery-1.10.js',null,null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'nprogress', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation/foundation.nprogress.js',null,null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'foundationmin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation/foundation.min.js',null,null, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'foundationscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation/foundation.scripts.js',null,null, true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundation_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundation_scripts' );

?>
```

I have my custom script file /js/foundation/foundation.scripts.js initializing foundation via:

```
jQuery(document).foundation(($);
```

In my header.php I have my title functions, basic meta, and the `wp_head`. Im really lost as to why my jquery isn't loading.

Side note: the jquery 1.10 is used ONLY to help nprogress.js work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I'm coming back to correct this post, having successfully wp_enqueue'd Foundation 5.3 for Sites to Wordpress 3.9. This code below is for **anyone** who has struggled to *WP_ENQUEUE* Foundation. The code below works perfectly.

**UPDATES:** I will continue to update this post with the newest version of Wordpress and Foundation to give you all the best *WP_ENQUEUE* code possible :) youre welcome!

[**Foundation 5.3 for Sites**](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Code below has been updated as of 6/24/14

```
add_action('init', 'styleEnqueue');
add_action('init', 'foundationEnqueue');

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// register and enqueue styles
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function styleEnqueue() {
  if (!is_admin()) {

// enqueue theme styles
wp_enqueue_style('css', get_template_directory_uri()."/css/YOUR_STYLESHEET_FILE_PATH_HERE_FROM_ROOT",array(),'','screen');
// enqueue foundation.min
wp_enqueue_style('css', get_template_directory_uri()."/css/foundation.min.css",array(),'5.1.1','screen');
// enqueue font icons
wp_enqueue_style('icons', get_template_directory_uri()."/css/foundation-icons.css",array(),'5.1.1','screen');
  }
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// register and enqueue scripts
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function foundationEnqueue() {
  if (!is_admin()) {

// deregister core jquery
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
// reregister jquery 2.1.0
wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/vendor/jquery.js", array(),'2.1.0',false);
// register modernizr
wp_register_script('modernizer', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/vendor/modernizr.js",array(jquery),'2.1.0', false);
// register foundation.min
wp_register_script('foundation', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/foundation.min.js", array('jquery'),'2.1.0',true); 
// register YOUR_JS_FILE_HERE
wp_register_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/YOUR_JS_FILE_HERE.js", array('jquery'),'2.1.0',true);

wp_enqueue_script(array('jquery','modernizer','foundation','customjs'));

  }
}
```

Comment: Good to know I wasn't wrong about the jquery depency. Just wasn't sure :-) Thanks for posting your answer. Deserves a +1... Period

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here, and some other things that I would do diffirently.

Lets start with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style). The first parameter here is `$handle`

> **$handle**
>
> (string) (required) Name used as a handle for the stylesheet. As a special case, if the string contains a '?' character, the preceding part of the string refers to the registered handle, and the succeeding part is appended to the URL as a query string.

As you can see here, this parameter only takes a string, not an array.  So this won't work

```
wp_enqueue_style(array(
      'reset','foundation','foundation-icons','project.override','nprogress')
  );
```

There is also no need to register the stylesheet first then enqueueing it. You can just enqueue the stylesheet. The reason being that you are not enqueueing the stylesheet more than once conditionally. So you can simply just do the following

```
 wp_enqueueu_style( 'foundation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/foundation.css' );
```

You should also be using: [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) instead of [`get_stylesheet_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri)

Now, the same would apply to [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Also the `$handle` parameter doesn't accept an array.

The important parameter here though is `$in_footer`

> **$in_footer**
>
> (boolean) (optional) Normally, scripts are placed in  of the HTML document. If this parameter is true, the script is placed before the  end tag. This requires the theme to have the wp_footer() template tag in the appropriate place.
>
> Default: false

If you need to load scripts in the footer, this parameter should be set to true

To move on, the same conditions would apply to `wp_enqueue_script()` as for `wp_enqueue_style()` regarding the fact that you don't need to register and enqueue, you can just enqueue, and the use of `get_template_directory_uri()`.

So you would do something like this to enqueue your script

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'scrollReveal', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation/foundation.scrollReveal.js',array(),false, false );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, it has helped me understand the syntax more. Unfortunately I was not able to solve this problem. Jquery still is not loading or initializing. My revised code is edited in my original post now, but am I supposed to put something else in my header.php? I thought enqueue was supposed to load when you call these:

    <? wp_head();?>
    
and in footer:

    <? wp_footer();?>

Comment: `add_action( 'init', 'foundation_scripts' );` is wrong. You should never use the `init` hook to enqueue scripts. You should always use `wp_enqueue_scripts` So change the code to `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundation_scripts' );`

Comment: I apologize, I tried "init" as a test and forgot to take it out. I have not enqueue'd the library. Is it:
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
? Do I enqueue jquery in the header.php or in my enqueue-scripts.php?

Comment: Jip. Just to make sue, are you using a parent(stand-alone) theme or a child theme.

Comment: I believe it is a parent theme. This is a custom framework I am making, taking a blank wordpress and adding foundation to it. I am overriding the foundation.css with my own override.css, but I do not believe I am doing a child theme. I hope I dont sound foolish if I am wrong.

Comment: You should try to change this piece of code `,null,null, false` and `,null,null, true` (3 last parameters for `wp_enqueue_script()`) to `,array(),false, false` and `,array(),false, true` respectively according to the codex`

Comment: OK, I'm not versed with foundation, but it seems it is dependant on jquery. Apartently the scripts also needs to be in a specific order

Comment: Foundation is a CSS responsive framework. Nothing more. The order I have it inside the footer.php on my working website is the same order I have on my test site. Its almost as if it cannot find the files... I verified that I am creating a parent theme, by the way. Should I initialize anything in the header or footer, or should wp_enqueue handle this?

Comment: There are scripts missing. When I inspect element using google chrome, the old site has plenty scripts from foundation, the new one only have 4.

Comment: Check [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/tags/wordpress) and [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-wordpress-themes-using-responsive-frameworks--wp-24867)

Comment: Just saw your links, I am checking them out now and will be testing (thank you SO much for all the help thus far, I sincerely appreciate it)

Comment: Check the two links I've given. It seems the scripts are jquery depended.

Comment: Looking into it. I am essentially scrapping everything I have a loading fresh. The incorporation method you linked me to is for Foundation 4, but the same principles apply. I will dig around to find a foundation 5 incorporation.

Comment: If you find a solution it would be great to post it as an answer to your own question. It will not only help others in future, but it will keep your question constructive, and if your answer is well constructed, you can earn yourself some reputation. Good luck

Comment: I will and I have not forgotten, I am rebuilding what I have from the ground up and will post my fix should I find one. Tis quite odd why this won't work but you have helped set me in the right direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck forward